# Return a word from a words array when the time is the one from the time array. Javascript - React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, timing, transcription

I am building a transcription service for audio or video file with React.

The backend is done and I'm getting those 2 arrays:

I have an array of time, in second:

```
const timing = [0, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9, 1.3, 2]
```

I also have an array of words:

```
const words = ["hello", "world", "I", "am", "John", "Smith"]
```

I want to highlight a word only when the timing is right.

Is there any other way than infinity of "if" statement?

```
if(time = timing[0]) {return words[0]}
if(time = timing[1]) {return words[1]}
...
if(time = timing[n]) {return words[n]}
```

(*time is equal the the video / audio player)

Thanks!

Comment: So the item from the `timing` array should equal `words` array ?

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier if you use dict and setInterval

```js
const words = {
    0: "hello",
  200: "world",
  800: "I",
  900: "am",
  1300: "John",
  2000: "Smith"
}

function speak(timing) {
    if(timing in words) {
    console.log(words[timing])
  }
}

current_timestamp = 0
function timer() {
    speak(current_timestamp)
  current_timestamp += 100
}
setInterval(timer, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const timing = [0, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9, 1.3, 2];
const words = ['hello', 'world', 'I', 'am', 'John', 'Smith'];

function getWord(timing, words, time) {
    return words[timing.indexOf(time)];
}

console.log(getWord(timing, words, 0.9));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this:

```js
const timing = [0, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9, 1.3, 2]

const words = ["hello", "world", "I", "am", "John", "Smith"];
var hashTable = {}
timing.forEach((i, index)=>{
  hashTable[i] = words[index];
});

console.log(hashTable)

   console.log(hashTable[timing[3]])
```